# Twitter Login with Kotlin

Tags: android, twitter, authentication, kotlin

Hello guys please I have spent the last four hours trying to implement the twitter login with my app following the documentation everything seems to work fine but for one or many reasons when i click connect or cancel on the twitter authorization page, i get this toast "this app is not permitted to perform this action twitter". I honestly dont know where to go from here. Here is my code. I know am doing something wrong, can anyone point me in the right direction please.

```
//on create
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
val config = TwitterConfig.Builder(this)
.logger(DefaultLogger(Log.DEBUG))
.twitterAuthConfig(TwitterAuthConfig(CONSUMER_KEY,   CONSUMER_SECRET))
            .debug(true)
            .build()
    Twitter.initialize(config)
loginTwitter.setCallback(object : Callback<TwitterSession>() {
override fun success(result: Result<TwitterSession>) {
val session = TwitterCore.getInstance().sessionManager.activeSession
val authToken = session.authToken
val token = authToken.token
val secret = authToken.secret
loginTwitterUser(session)
}

override fun failure(exception: TwitterException) {
Log.d("twitter error: ","Something went wrong, please try again")
}
})
}

//onActivityResult
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int,
data:Intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    loginTwitter.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}

//the crash log
```

04-09 23:00:47.967 14143-14143/com.arcadiamobiletv.amtv E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.arcadiamobiletv.amtv, PID: 14143
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=140, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.arcadiamobiletv.amtv/com.arcadiamobiletv.amtv.Controllers.LoginActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter data
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4178)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4221)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1583)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter data
        at com.arcadiamobiletv.amtv.Controllers.LoginActivity.onActivityResult(LoginActivity.kt)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6919)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4174)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4221) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1583) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924) 
04-09 23:00:54.243 14143-14154/com.arcadiamobiletv.amtv I/art: Enter while loop.

Comment: I see no one has an answer to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After days of debugging I found out nothing was wrong with my code, i had to whitelist my app from twitter. Secondly i took a shorter route using this awesome library instead of reinventing the will - https://github.com/jaychang0917/SimpleAuth